# TensorFlow: print output value from each iteration

Tags: tensorflow

I'm experimenting with TensorFlow to get the hang of it. Trying to create a version of basic MNIST example by reading lines from a CSV file instead of images. I'm piecing the code together based on the MNIST example and the CSV feeder example.

The first 100 cells in each line of my CSV represent an "image" of a number, and next 10 cells in the same row represent a "label" that identifies that image, similarly to the label in the MNIST example.

I'm trying to print what TensorFlow actually estimates the number to be during each iteration over the CSV lines by printing the actual label and the "guessed" output side-by-side for each iteration. But it looks like what I'm actually printing is the true label both times, since the `y` variable requires me to feed the current `x` values to replace the x placeholder.

How can I print out the guess, rather than the actual label for each iteration?

My code looks like this:

```
fileName = 'TEST_data/TFTest.csv'

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([fileName])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

rDefaults = []
for i in range(0,110):
  rDefaults.append((list([0])))

data = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=rDefaults)
fPack = tf.slice(data, [0], [100])
lPack = tf.slice(data, [100], [10])

features =  tf.pack(fPack)
label = tf.pack(lPack)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 100])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    i = 0
    for i in range(10):
        f, l = sess.run([features, label])
        f1 = np.reshape(f, (-1, 100))
        l1 = np.reshape(l, (-1, 10))
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: f1, y_: l1})
        if i%1==0:
            print(sess.run(tf.argmax(l1, 1)))
            print(sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: f1}))
            print('********')
        i = i + 1

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 0):

this line returns you the index of the highest value inside the softmax y

```
print(sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: f1}))
```

if you want to print such value then you have to fetch the value at that index.

```
print(sess.run(y[tf.argmax(y, 1)], feed_dict={x: f1}))
```

if I understood correctly your queston.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the above, but it's not quite what I was asking: why my predictions always come out exactly the same as the actual labels. The output vector looks random-ish, but highest value always matches true label, TF can't be that good! Even with random 0s and 1s in the first 100 cells of Xs, sess.run(y) always shows the guess that corresponds to the labels 100%. I'm wondering if it's because Y depends on a placeholder for x'es, which I have to serve via feed_dict to get the value of Ys, or most likely because I'm doing something completely wrong in the whole logic of the program?

Comment: what does it print for you the above code? not having that input csv file I can't reproduce. But it can get to 100% accuracy if the dataset is small and the network has enough capacity to memorize the entire dataset (overfitting) ...

Comment: Hmm. maybe you are right and it's just overfitting, as this is indeed a very small data set just for testing. The output looks like this: if the actual label is like this [0,0,1,0], then the guessed output would be [0,0,0,0] before you run sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: f1, y_: l1}) and something like [.91, .91, 15.1, .85] after you run the train_step. So it DOES seem that the train_step does the right thing, as before it everything is initialized to zeroes and after it's a non-normalized output with correct guess. I'm just concerned why it's always 100% accurate, even with random data.

Comment: in terms of what input data looks like -- it's just a CSV with a bunch of zeroes and 1s. Each line is 110 cells. First 100 cells represent an "object" and the following 10 cells represent the label for that object, with 10 possible classifications, so all zeroes except the nth element, which is a 1, reflecting which case this row is. So basically trying to replicate the MNIST logic, but with a 100-long input "image" and a 10-long label for that image.

Comment: Also, come to think of it: my batch size is essentially 1. That's probably why it's easy for TF to minimize the cost for each iteration perfectly? Haven't yet figured out how to get the batch read working with CSV, so I thought I'd give it a try with line-by-line first and maybe that's where the problem is...

Comment: Just to confirm, that does, indeed, seem to be the problem. Finally got batches to work with CSV and it seems that now that things are fed in multiple rows, it has a hard time guessing form the start, but learns quickly...